# Prevent mouse from auto-moving to a Windows 10 notification icon when using keyboard navigation

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, ux

I'm using the keyboard for most of my computer activities. Firstly, when I press Win+B to focus on the Notification Area, then navigate to an icon I want to interact with, and finally press one of: space, enter, or menu key, the mouse pointer will auto-move to that icon.

The mouse will focus on the icon it is pointing at after hovering over it for a while when I am trying to navigate to another icon, pretty much forcing me to move the mouse elsewhere anyway.